# Error in using Sqlite query in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am sqlite3 in my app, inserting, updating, deleting everything works perfectly.
I have an autoincrement statement. I want to initialise it, so i have used the following method

```
+(void) initializeSNo
{
NSString * query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET SEQ=0 WHERE NAME='WineLists'"];
sqlite3_stmt * statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)) 
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
    }

}
}
```

I have used this method as

```
[Database initializeSNo];
```

But, the autoincremented value doesnt initialise when the method is called. Where I am wrong

Comment: What is the error ? Why you need to initialize the auto increment field ?

Comment: yes, SNo is the field which auto increments, i want to initialise it, wen the app loads, so i have called that method in appdelegate

Comment: What is the error you are getting then ? You didn't open the database in your code

Comment: it is not initialised

Comment: i have done everything, inserting, deleting, updating etc, only the auto increment is not getting initilised

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47320/discussion-between-chandru-and-midhun-mp)